# Thunderbird font

Tags: email, fonts, thunderbird

here in my Mozilla Thunderbird I receive mails everyday, but some of them are really a mess. Here is an example:

¨.g
†âUÕ‹@¯)Û¤dÊ\Šª!€þ>èy—ß_u¤U>.«lÏ§A#¼—zqèd*laÙ‰öé‚OMØ1dx]•xùÂPÆïUêf'í³-Í[%`]€÷¥µ[«!#ÚËŸ·”¹½vg95U  «újõx¶ÎDøñk€kÓ‹=ƒÆ¾ºM`h¥Pà®nƒ_øëm!R¿ŸþÝ)…v¥W-Wd„ÆöÙ÷r}±Ð\ômN–°oñBÝÔÐ)0„_º‚r!ÜßT<‚¨ÿ6CÔ'^¶,‘uÀ´èÓƒ=/¬ºf)÷C‹Lû˜&¦?";õyé¨¿Ì¥hžp¤?gŒPfô>aÕqZÆ¥p#ó´–j— öx·2½¤ZVV;ði)4

any idea how I can fix this ?
Thx in advance

Comment: Should they be legit mails? If not, filter them as spam?

Comment: Some of them are from clients

Comment: Do they use some funky encoding? Does the source of the message look OK? Are they text or HTML?

Comment: It display's name and contact information, the subject comply to our firm but I can't read the email to see what is in it

Comment: seth  - I don't know, it is possible, here is set to UNICODE(UTF-8)

Comment: Bigger question would be: Which language is the mail supposed to be in? Anything using Western/Latin characters? Or Asian?

Comment: I guess Western/Latin. We don't coresponde to Asia

Comment: Could you show the entire message from "View Source" (Ctrl+U)?